# Javascript: code with no animation with requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javacript and test the code from the book (below). It should animate an image but doesn't. I add print out using alert which shows that the function is executed only once. What goes wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> My home page </title>
  <script>
var cat = document.querySelector("img");
var angle = 0, lastTime = null;
var count = 0;
function animate(time) {
  //alert(count);
  //++count;
  if (lastTime != null)
    angle += (time - lastTime) * 0.001;
  lastTime = time ;
  cat.style.top = (Math.sin(angle) * 20) + "px";
  cat.style.left = (Math.cos(angle) * 200) + "px";
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p style ="text-align: center">
    <img src ="img/cat.jpg" style ="position: relative">
  </p >
</body>
<script>requestAnimationFrame(animate);</script>
</html>
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the console, you will see that the `cat` is `undefined`.

This happens because `var cat = document.querySelector("img");` is run in the `head` element and so the `img` does not exist yet.

If you move the code at the end of the `body` it will work.
Or you could run your code when the `DOMContentLoaded` event is fired.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title> My home page </title>
</head>
<body>
  <p style ="text-align: center">
    <img src ="img/cat.jpg" style ="position: relative">
  </p >
</body>
<script>
var cat = document.querySelector("img");
var angle = 0, lastTime = null;
var count = 0;
function animate(time) {
  //alert(count);
  //++count;
  if (lastTime != null)
    angle += (time - lastTime) * 0.001;
  lastTime = time ;
  cat.style.top = (Math.sin(angle) * 20) + "px";
  cat.style.left = (Math.cos(angle) * 200) + "px";
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
</script>
<script>requestAnimationFrame(animate);</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the browser see a `<script>` tag, he stop rendering the page, and run the code inside.

So, the problem in the code that the line `var cat = document.querySelector("img");` happen before the img is append to the document, so you query get nothing.

the only change you need to do- is to move the  `var cat = document.querySelector("img");` to under the `body`, like so:

```
</body>
<script>
    var cat = document.querySelector("img");
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
</script>

</html>
```